# Multiple includes in PHP script called via command line

Tags: php, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on creating some scheduled tasks that perform system maintenance on my database (i.e. inactive user cleanup, data archiving, etc.) and also generate/email automated data reporting.

Currently I have it setup so that each task is its own file and there is a master file that calls the appropriate tasks.

For example:

```
run_daily.php
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db/connect.db.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/definitions.inc.php';
$get_dailyTasks = mysql_query("SELECT task_name FROM task_scheduler WHERE task_type='task' AND task_occurs='daily' AND task_active=1");
while(($dailyTasks = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_dailyTasks)))
{
  include $schedule.'tasks/'$dailyTasks['task_name'].$tsk;
};
$get_dailyReports = mysql_query("SELECT task_name FROM task_scheduler WHERE task_type='report' AND task_occurs='daily' AND task_active=1");
while(($dailyReports = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_dailyReports)))
{
  include $schedule.'reports/'.$dailyReports['task_name'].$rbf;
};
?>

user_cleanup.php
<?php
$disable_inactive = "UPDATE users SET enabled='no' WHERE (created < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND last_active IS NULL AND enabled='yes') OR (last_active < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND enabled='yes')";
mysql_query($disable_inactive);
?>
```

I'm attempting to set it up this way because I plan on having the master file run via command line and scheduled as a task scheduler job on the server.  I will have access to modify the files as needed but I will not easily be able to change what is scheduled to run once it is setup.  My thought was to schedule a master task and this would allow me to add/remove sub-tasks as needed.

The problem I'm running into though is that when I test everything via command line, the sub-task never seems to return control to the main task.  After the first sub-task runs (regardless of how I order them) none of the other sub-tasks after it run.

Comment: what happens when you try to access the sub-task directly? Can you post the code of it? maybe it is exiting due to an error, you you have  a `exit;` or `die;` command in there somewhere-- we'd need to see the code of the sub-task to comment further.

Comment: Post the full code of run_daily.php and one of the included tasks. You seem to have a problem somewhere in there, because it should work as it is.

Comment: I posted the full code for run_daily and user_cleanup.  Everything runs successfully if I run it outside of the command line.